# Display CircularProgressIndicator while logging a user in

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, async-await, future, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm currently working on a login screen for a Flutter app by following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6kaEbTfb444) video. Hence, my code is almost completely identical to the code to this video on [GitHub](https://github.com/MarcusNg/flutter_login_ui).

I added a way to store the email and password of the user in the current state and also added a CircularProgressIndicator to the login button as soon as the button is pressed.

The latter is done by the following code (I removed all the style-related code to make it a bit more readable):

```
  Widget _buildLoginBtn() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.0),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: _isLoggingIn ? Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Login"),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              child: SizedBox(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ) : Text("Login"),
        onPressed: () => _handleLogin(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Originally, I just wanted to test, whether changing the state really leads to the CircularProgressIndicator being displayed by setting `_isLoggingIn` to `true`.

After I saw that this is working just fine, I wanted to make it, so that the CircularProgressIndicator disappears again after some time (e.g. in case the login attempt is rejected). Hence, as I haven't set up an API by now, I just wanted the application to wait for some seconds before turning the progress bar off by setting `_isLoggingIn` to `false` again.

However, it turns out that thereby nothing happens visibly (only console outputs that indicate the waiting), or - in case I had `_isLoggingIn` previously set to `true` - the progress bar just stops spinning for 3 seconds and then disappears.

This is the result of the following code:

```
  void _handleLogin() {
    setState(() {
      _isLoggingIn = true;
    });

    print("Start Logging In");

    sleep(Duration(seconds: 3));

    print("Stop Logging In");

    setState(() {
      _isLoggingIn = false;
    });

  }
```

From a logical point of view this seems very logical as I basically just block the main thread, so the UI is only updated after I set `_isLoggingIn` to `true` and to `false` again.

I instantly thought about some functionality for async processing. I read some things on `async-await`, the `Future` function type and the `FutureBuilder` but as I'm pretty new to Flutter I didn't really grasp which functions to make async and also which function type I need to convert to `Future<void>` or how to properly trigger the async processing. Also I didn't really deal with `Futures` and `async-await` statements prior to this.

So I hope someone could give me some insight into this topic and how to solve this problem properly?

Answer (score 0):

I always use a Flutter package [EasyLoading](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_easyloading) because it simplifies that process!
there will no need for using a bool and setstate to add a circularprogressIndicator.

```
import 'package:flutter_easyloading/flutter_easyloading.dart';


  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 // This widget is the root of your application. (main.dart)
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter EasyLoading',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter EasyLoading'),
   //initialize Easyloading
  builder: EasyLoading.init(),
    );
  }
 }

Widget _buildLoginBtn() {
return Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.0),
  child: ElevatedButton(
    child: Text("Login"),
    onPressed: () => _handleLogin(),
  ),
 );
 }

void _handleLogin() {
EasyLoading.show(dismissOnTap: false, status: "Loading...");
print("Start Logging In");

sleep(Duration(seconds: 3));

print("Stop Logging In");
EasyLoading.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: I tried to use it but somehow I wasn't able to implement it properly. Although looking at the examples on the respective pub.dev I couldn't really figure out how to properly implement it so that it does something. For me at least, it simply doesn't display anything.

Wouldn't it make more sense to rely on an async function that "fetches the data" (i.e. pretends to do so by waiting) and resets the state after waiting? The problem is I don't know when and how to call what type of function. Currently I tried `Future<void> _fetchData()  async {sleep(); setState(({...}))}`.

Comment: I forgot to add the initialize in the materialApp in main.dart, check the edit @Samaranth

Comment: I already saw that in the official documentation on pub.dev and also included it, but it didn't change anything for me. However, I found a way to solve my problem which I also posted as an answer. Thanks for your effort though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need package use mvvm format and also for indicator there will be a widget name CupertinoActivityIndicator use that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found [this article](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/showing-a-progress-indicator-easily-in-flutter-aa564eb0df5c) where the user interaction with the application during data loading is discussed and a solution is presented. Finally I switched to a dialog which displays a `CircularProgressIndicator` while loading and blocking any UI interaction in the meantime.

Thereby the user won't be able to send multiple login requests at once while also indicating to the user that data is being loaded.

With the help of this article my app finally behaves as I wanted.

For anyone encountering a similar problem I highly suggest reading through that article and considering to use the code presented there. However, additional null-safety checks need to be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

## ProgressIndicator - 3 ways

Here are 3 different ways we could hide / disable a login button & show/hide a progress indicator:

- `showDialog` (i.e. a `ModalBarrier`)
- `StatefulWidget`
- `ValueListenableBuilder`

`showDialog` pushes & pops a semi-transparent barrier (route/page) on top.

`StatefulWidget` & `ValueListenableBuilder` rebuild themselves to remove/replace widgets.

### `showDialog`

`showDialog` internally uses a `ModalBarrier` to block interaction with widgets underneath.

This doesn't require keeping any state.

We just block interaction/show a spinner while login is ongoing and then `pop()` the barrier page/route when we're done (or timeout duration is met).

```
class ProgressShowDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Center(
      child: OutlinedButton(
        child: Text('Login'),
        onPressed: () async => login(context)
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> login(BuildContext context) async {
    // show (push onto route stack) a modal barrier, blocking UI
    showDialog(context: context,
        builder: (context) => Center(child: SizedBox(height:30, width: 30,
            child: CircularProgressIndicator())), barrierDismissible: false);

    // a fake login call using Future.delayed
    bool loginOK = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () => true)
        .timeout(Duration(seconds: 5), onTimeout: () => false);

    // dispose the dialog modal barrier (pop it from route stack)
    Navigator.of(context).pop(loginOK);

    // do something with login result
    print('Login OK? $loginOK');
  }
}
```

Note: we can set a timeout/handler for any `Future` using `.timeout()`.

### `StatefulWidget`

Here we use a state variable `isLoggingIn` and call `setState()` when we change its value, to rebuild the `StatefulWidget`, to show/hide the form/progress indicator.

```
class ProgressStateful extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProgressStatefulState createState() => _ProgressStatefulState();
}

class _ProgressStatefulState extends State<ProgressStateful> {
  bool isLoggingIn = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Center(
      child: _loginFormOrProgress,
    );
  }

  Widget get _loginFormOrProgress {
    // if log in ongoing, show spinner
    if (isLoggingIn) {
      return SizedBox(height: 80, width: 80, child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
    }
    else {
      // otherwise show login form
      return OutlinedButton(
          child: Text('Login'),
          onPressed: () async => login(context)
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> login(BuildContext context) async {
    loginOngoing(true); // rebuild, show spinner/hide login btn

    bool loginOK = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () => true)
        .timeout(Duration(seconds: 5),
        onTimeout: () => false);

    // Do something fun with login results
    print('Login OK? $loginOK');

    loginOngoing(false); // rebuild & hide spinner/show form
  }

  void loginOngoing(bool loginOngoing) {
    setState(() {
      isLoggingIn = loginOngoing;
    });
  }
}
```

### `ValueListenableBuilder`

This is similar to `StatefulWidget` except using some Flutter foundation classes ([`ValueNotifier`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html) & `ValueListenableBuilder`) to handle rebuilding (calling of `setState()`) for us.

```
class ProgressValueListenable extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProgressValueListenableState createState() => _ProgressValueListenableState();
}

class _ProgressValueListenableState extends State<ProgressValueListenable> {
  ValueNotifier<bool> loginOngoing = ValueNotifier(false);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ValueListenableBuilder( // rebuilds whenever loginOngoing changes (receives an event)
          valueListenable: loginOngoing,
          builder: (context, value, child) {
            // if login ongoing, show spinner
            if (value) {
              return SizedBox(height: 80, width: 80, child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
            }
            else {
              // otherwise show login form
              return OutlinedButton(
                  child: Text('Login'),
                  onPressed: () async => login()
              );
            }
          }),
    );
  }

  void login() async {
    loginOngoing.value = true; // show spinner

    // login call happens here ↓
    bool loginOK = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () => true)
        .timeout(Duration(seconds: 2),
        onTimeout: () => false);

    // Do something fun with login results
    print('Login OK? $loginOK');

    loginOngoing.value = false; // hide spinner
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    loginOngoing.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```